# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Android:Theme.Material'

Tags: android

I am trying to use `material Theme` with following code

My styles.xml  file

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Android:Theme.Material">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

While doing this i am getting following error :

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Android:Theme.Material'
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Open up the `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` then upload their content.

Comment: what is your target sdk into project property?

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps
1. first of all define a new xml file in your res/values folder name(color.xml).
2. then define your custom color as.

```
<resources>
<color name="primary">#03f</color>
</resources>
```

The problem is that your theme has provided a place to customize but it does not know @color/primary this thing.

now try again to run the project.

remember **Set android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L"**

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L"`.

You need to do following steps

- `compileSdkVersion` is set to 'android-L'
- `minSdkVersion` is set to 'L'
- `targetSdkVersion` is set to 'L'

---

Read more about [***Create a Project using Andoid L***](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html#createProject)

Answer (score 0):

The @Pankaj answer was correct at time of writing. Now API 21 are officially released, and something is changed.

To use the Material Theme in your project you have to:

- use API 21 **to compile** (it is required)

Then you can choose one of these:

- use the minSdkVersion=21 and values folder
- use the Theme.Material **only** in values-v21 folder.
- use the AppCompat Theme in values folder.