# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:color Primary')

Tags: android, material-design

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
   <!-- Main theme colors -->
   <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
   <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
   <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
   <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
   <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
   <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

Please try to resolve the problem.

Comment: Post full error message.

Comment: Check also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257737/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`android:Theme.Material` requires API level 21 and so it's cleared that your `minSDKVersion` is lower than 21.

If you really want to develop app for API 21 then declare `android:minSDKVersion=21`.

And if in case you want to provide compatibility to lower version then you need to use [support library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7), which is commonly known as AppCompat library.

You can access above attributes using AppCompat:

```
 <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/primary</item>
 <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@color/primary_dark</item>
```

Comment: The important point is to use API 21 to compile.
You can also use the Material Theme only in values-v21 folder, without using minsdk=21 or appCompat.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That could be the solution if he wants to target API level >=21, with keeping that point in mind I have suggested compatibility solution :)

Comment: @PareshMayani can you specify what difference it makes between writing android:colorPrimary and simply colorPrimary in the item tag.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can use this attribute, using the support library:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">...</item>
</style>
```

You can also use the others:

```
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">...</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">...</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:colorPrimary` is supported only from API level 21. You can see the error message in android studio and in eclipse below:

`android:colorPrimary` requires API level 21 (current min is 14)
[image]

Comment: see my image if you really think its copied