# No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'

Tags: android, eclipse

Please Help Me.. Where I'm Wrong??

[Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb7wH.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joFNB.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881072/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-androidcolor-primary

Comment: Also if possible put the code in your post next time. Otherwise imgur might delete the images in the future, and important information on the question might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you:-

```
 <resources>
 <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
 <!-- Main theme colors -->
 <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
 <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
 <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
 <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
 <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
 <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
 </style>
</resources>
```

find [here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette)